# How to store and display one to many relationship in laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, erd

[image: this is my erd design]

I want to create API store function and display course and curriculum detail like this ERD, but I don't know how to make it

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Curriculum extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the course that owns the comment.
     */
     public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class,'course_id', 'id'));
    }
}
```

Once the relationship has been defined, we can Store

```
use App\Models\Curriculum;
use App\Models\Course;

$course = Course::whereId($id)->first(); //it will give you a collection of Course model

Curriculum::create([    
        'name' => 'testing'
        'course_id' => $course->id

    ]);
```

Once the relationship has been defined, we can retrieve a Curriculum's parent course by accessing the course "dynamic relationship property":

```
use App\Models\Curriculum;

$curriculum = Curriculum::find(1);

return $curriculum->course->title_course;
```